# yii2 2amigos google maps

Tags: google-maps, yii2

I am using Yii2 2amigos/google maps.
Could someone explain how this works?

I am getting the following error:
Class 'vendor\dosamigos\google\maps\LatLng' not found

I thought the file path to latLng would be what is above, however the file path in my vendor is:
vendor/2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library/latlng

Not sure about the error displayed

Edit:  Thanks gmc for your help

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use backend\models\House;
use dosamigos\google\maps\LatLng;
use dosamigos\google\maps\services\DirectionsWayPoint;
use dosamigos\google\maps\services\TravelMode;
use dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\PolylineOptions;
use dosamigos\google\maps\services\DirectionsRenderer;
use dosamigos\google\maps\services\DirectionsService;
use dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\InfoWindow;
use dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\Marker;
use dosamigos\google\maps\Map;
use dosamigos\google\maps\services\DirectionsRequest;
use dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\Polygon;
use dosamigos\google\maps\layers\BicyclingLayer;

    $coord = new LatLng(['lat' => 39.720089311812094, 'lng' =>     2.91165944519042]);
$map = new Map([
'center' => $coord,
'zoom' => 14,
]);

// Display the map -finally :)
echo $map->display();
```

Edit 2:
Problem was that guzzlehttp 4 ,updated to guzzlehttp 6 and it works.
Thanks for the help gmc and touqeer.

Comment: Do you have the following `use dosamigos\google\maps\LatLng;` at the beginning of your view?

Comment: Yes I followed the docs.  Trying to load what is in the example

Comment: Your vendor path is correct, I don't know what else recommend unless you post your code

Comment: I edited with the view code.

Comment: remove `vendor\ ` from all your use statements

Comment: Still could not find it.  Class 'dosamigos\google\maps\LatLng' not found

Comment: do try with `\dosamigos\google\maps\LatLng;` adding \ before every dosamigos classes

Comment: Still the same error:     Class 'dosamigos\google\maps\LatLng' not found

Comment: In `composer.json` you have this, right? `"2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library" : "*",`

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: I'm out of ideas here. You have the files in that location, right? Do you use PhpStorm IDE?

Comment: I am using Sublime Text.

Answer (score 1):

Please Install composer first from yii2 site then hit the following code in the command prompt in your www basic/advance template directory.

make sure you have the use dosamigos code in your site view file

use dosamigos\google\maps\LatLng;
i.e

```
C:\> composer require "2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library" "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem under the vendor folder go to the yii2soft folder and open the extensions.php file and add the following code:

```
  '2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library' => 
   array (
       'name' => '2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library',
       'version' => '9999999-dev',
       'alias' => 
            array (
                 '@dosamigos/google/maps' => $vendorDir . '/2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library',
            ),
   ),
```